# Pass command to existing ipython kernel

Tags: kernel, persistence, ipython

I would like to run a function command from the terminal command line of an exiting ipython kernel. Here is a simple version of the kernel I am running:

```
#load necessary modules:
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from mymodule import preprocess
import pandas as pd

#create gensim model:
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)

#create function for processing data and IO:
def createpreprocess(dfdirin, dfdirout):
    df = pd.read_csv(dfdirin)
    X = preprocess(df, model)
    X.to_csv(dfdirout)
```

where preprocess is some gensim function I want to run. I would like to call this from the command line with something like this

```
ipython console --existing -c "createpreprocess('filein.csv','fileout.csv')"
```

the function is working fine from the notebook kernel, just showing the gensim here to show that it would be very useful to call this already loaded kernel.

I am working on the localhost of a mac with ipython 3.1.0. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, just moved this over to flask. Still curious how to do this in the ipython --existing framework, but this task is more appropriate for a simple api.

Comment: I don't think we have a command that can directly send code to an existing kernel, but it wouldn't be hard to write a script using the [jupyter_client](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/index.html) API that could do that.